# JEditorPane - switching back to the default editor kit

Tags: java, swing, jeditorpane, defaultstyleddocument

If you change the editor kit of a `JEditorPane` to `HTMLEditorKit`, how do you change it back to the default (plain text) editor kit, like how it is when you first instantiate one? I want it to do this so that I can load all of the html and display it as plain text, not as formatted text, when the user switches to html mode (I'm making a dreamweaver-type app).
I tried:

```
DefaultEditorKit kit = new DefaultEditorKit();
page.setEditorKit(kit);
```

But that makes the editor pane uneditable. How can I switch the editor kit back to plain text?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As discussed in [*Editor Panes vs. Text Panes*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/editorpane.html#recap), "Be aware that the document and editor kit might change when using the `setPage()` method." For plain text, they recommend a `DefaultStyledDocument` and `StyledEditorKit`.